# Date iso format python

Tags: python, date, formatdatetime

I have this date form in python that I am writing on an api: 2022-06-01T10:36:56.000Z How can I turn this into a second? Thanks for your comments

I would like to use the seconds I have to do addition division and then go back to day/date/hour format

I can't find any content on the internet

Comment: I don't think Python can deal with the time zone designation `Z` without using an external library.

Comment: what do you mean "*turn this into a second*" ?

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot handle all type of iso formatted date strings. So you can use `isodate` library or remove `.000Z` from the string parsing.

You can be more clear on seconds though, is it total seconds elapsed from 1970, Jan 1 or seconds part in the date ?

```
k = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-06-01T10:36:56.000Z".replace(".000Z", ""))
k.timestamp()
```

Comment: Yes I was talking about the total seconds. I will try what you suggested